# DOMPDF adding footer to PDF but when printing it doesn't print

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

Im using DOMPDF to do html->PDF. It all works well but my issues is IM using

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
   left: 0;
    right: 0;
    //color: #aaa;
    //font-size: 0.9em;
}
#footer {
bottom: 15;
border-top: 0.1pt solid #aaa
}
```

and

```
<div id="footer">
<p class="center"><small>$settings_business_name, $setting_address, $setting_city, $setting_state $setting_zip - Phone: $setting_phone_office~; if ($setting_phone_cell) { print $fileHandle qq~ - Direct Cell: $setting_phone_cell~;} print $fileHandle qq~ <br>Email: $setting_email_billing<br />
Please make checks payable to: $settings_business_name</small></p>
</div> <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
```

which displays on the pdf as expected, my problem is when a user goes to print a hardcopy on paper the footer goes away. Am I doing something wrong? The footer displays on the pdf but when you go to print the PDF it doesn't print.

Comment: Is this in all cases? Is the footer maybe being cut off because it doesn't fall within the printable area of the page for the user's printer?

Comment: It happens with everything generated with that template. Typically its either invoices and or estimates. I'm not sure how to check to see if its falling off because of the printable area but I'd assume that since I'm using `bottom: 15;` it would ensure that its okay? When the pdf is generated it shows on the pdf it's self okay and when I do a print preview it shows okay.

Comment: I only ask because if the PDF viewer is not set to shrink-to-fit the page on printing it could cut off around the edges. 15 may or may not be enough, depending on the site of the footer. Can you share the PDF?